# How to add action bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I want to add action bar on top of my activity. How to add action bar in the following layout.
And I want to create action bar for API level less than 11. Can anyone provide me tutorial reference of that.

Layout-

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/buddha"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <View
        android:id="@+id/top1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="5"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/hist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#73000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/btxt"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/his"
    />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/top2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight=".10"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/typ"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#73000000"
        android:textSize="@dimen/btxt"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/typ"
    />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/top3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight=".10"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ben"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/btxt"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#73000000"
        android:text="@string/ben"
    />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/top4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight=".10"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/btxt"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#73000000"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/exit"
    />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/top41"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight=".10"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try [actionbarsherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

Comment: I am using support library.

Comment: check out the sample section in provided link above, you will get an idea of how to add actionbarsherlock in your app

Comment: i think you have to check this : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/index.html after that use actionbarsherlock library for < 3.0 android os or actionbarcompat also check this http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html

Comment: How about using **`AppCompat`** library instead of `ActionBarSherlock`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setup your project to **appcompat v7** library for reference see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Adding 
 and

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME
        | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
  }
```

Comment: @PareshMayani can you tell me any link to explain how to add icons in actionbar on particular position? Thank u for above link.

Comment: @JohnR read this article it might be helpful to you http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html

Answer (score 1):

The compatibility library has support for actionbar that works on old devices. This blog post explains how to use it and provides code samples: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html

Comment: The action bar is not part of your xml layout. It's being added by the system if you extend https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html  You will also have to change the style of your app to use Theme.AppCompat. Please check the link I added in my response, as it gives you all the steps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `menu.xml` files in `res/menu` folder.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
        android:title="Refresh"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="Settings">
    </item>

</menu>
```

Then, you need to inflate and add it in your actionbar using `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method in your `MainActivity` class.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
   return true;
}
```

And since you want to use action bar on API level less than 11, there are two popular options

- to use [actionbarsherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)
- or ActionBarCompat library from android support library (which you can find in android developer page).

ActionBarSherlock tutorial: [Adding ActionBarSherlock to Your Project](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-actionbarsherlock-to-your-project/)