# How to add actionbar menu from mainactivity to another activity?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I was wondering if someone could help me with a question I have about the actionbar? I recently had trouble with another activity in my android app but got that fix by setting `apptheme.noactionbar` in my manifest file but now decided. I think I would like to have an actionbar menu on my other activity like I have on my MainActivity page. I been looking up answers on adding an actionbar menu to my second activity but couldn't figure out how to do it. I try several answers but they aren't working for me. I even try switching `apptheme.noactionbar` to `apptheme.actionbar` and it still not helping. I did find some other new answer on how to add the actionbar but I not sure if I can remove the toolbar code in my OnCreate method and replace it with the [code (found in this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427533/how-to-add-action-bar). So, I not sure if I'm doing it right, if I missing something I'm suppose to added to make it work or if I'm not understand it right that it will't work?

I just not sure what to do, I done advance coding before but never did an actionbar menu before on an activity. I did make another menu in the menu folder, so that the menu of this activity would be different than the menu from the MainActivity. So, I will post my here below and was wondering if anyone would please look at it and tell me what I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for the help!

**My Code**

New Activity (trying to add actionbar menu to activity that app starts after MainActivity)

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class results extends MainActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.results);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_results, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here the code for my new activity, if any other parts of my app source is need, please let me know. I will post it here then.

**Any suggestions?**

Comment: use fragments for same toolbar everywhere and add it in main activity's container  or you have to add seprate toolbar in each activity

Comment: Hi dharmx, thank you for the reply.  When you say "use fragments", how do I do that?  Can you do an example code of what you want me to do? I'm sorry about asking for an example, I done some advance android coding before but have never work with any fragments in my code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just extend activity with main activity in which you want actionbar.

Comment: Hi Deep Doshi, thank you for the reply. When you say "just extend activity with main activity". Do you mean `results extends actionbar` or `results extends with activity'`? Or do you mean set the actionbar to extend to the second activity as well? I was wondering because I tried doing **results extends appcompat** but couldn't get it to work. Also do you think maybe I should add `ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();` to my onCreate method and see if it could put the actionbar into the activity? Thanks

Comment: in which activity you want action bar?

Comment: Hi Deep Doshi, Thank you for the reply. Sorry about the very late reply. I couldn't figure this out so I move on from this. The activity I wanted the action bar is my second activity.